# A private vector of pointers pointing to objects. How to access those objects with getter method?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, vector, getter

My program is six iterations of a loop in which eight people vote for one another. Who each person votes for during each iteration is saved to the private class member `voteList` (a vector of pointers).

My trouble is that at the end of the six iterations, I want to be able to say, for example, who Anna voted for during each vote, using the `GetVote(int)` public method I wrote.

`*(voteList[round])` should be the value (a person) of who Anna voted for in a given round, I think? And using the `GetName()` method should retrieve the string of that person's name. But no matter how I fiddle with it, the program crashes whenever I call `GetVote()`.

I'm sure I've made one or more really stupid mistakes, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any input would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

enum gender { male, female };

class Person {
    private:
        string personName;
        gender personGender;
        vector<Person *> voteList;
    public:
        // Constructors
        Person (string, gender);
        // Setters
        void Vote (Person * target) {
            voteList.push_back (target); 
        };
        // Getters
        string GetName () { return personName; };
        string GetVote (int round)
        {
            Person ugh = *(voteList[round]);
            return ugh.GetName ();
        };
};

Person::Person (string a, gender b) {
    personName = a;
    personGender = b; }

void Voting (vector<Person> voters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voters.size(); i++) {
        int number = (rand() % voters.size());
        Person * myTarget = &voters[number];
        voters[i].Vote (myTarget);
        cout << voters[i].GetName() << " votes for " << voters[number].GetName() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    Person Anna ("Anna", female);
    Person Baxter ("Baxter", male);
    Person Caroline ("Caroline", female);
    Person David ("David", male);
    Person Erin ("Erin", female);
    Person Frank ("Frank", male);
    Person Gemma ("Gemma", female);
    Person Hassan ("Hassan", male);

    vector<Person> theGroup;
    theGroup.push_back (Anna);
    theGroup.push_back (Baxter);
    theGroup.push_back (Caroline);
    theGroup.push_back (David);
    theGroup.push_back (Erin);
    theGroup.push_back (Frank);
    theGroup.push_back (Gemma);
    theGroup.push_back (Hassan);

    for (int n = 0, iterations = (theGroup.size() - 2); n <= iterations; n++)
        Voting (theGroup);

    cout << "ANNA VOTED FOR...";
    for (int n = 0; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        cout << "Round " << (n + 1) << ": " << Anna.GetVote(n) << '\n';
    }

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: afaik std::vector will allocate the objects on the heap, so it would be no point in allocating memory to store a pointer to another heap space. but anyways ... your `GetVote(int)` member needs a check if the `round` is less or equal the count of objects of your `voteList`. the rest is explained by Nbr44 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're copying your `Person` objects all over the place. For example when adding your `Person` objects to the `theGroup` vector and again when passing that same vector to the `Voting` function.

Copying persons doesn't semantically make any sense. In order to avoid this you should add a private copy constructor and assignment operator to your `Person` class:

```
private:
    Person(const Person& other);
    Person& operator=(const Person& rhs);
```

Next you're going to have to change your vectors to use `Person` pointers:

```
    vector<Person *> theGroup;
    theGroup.push_back (&Anna);
    theGroup.push_back (&Baxter);
    theGroup.push_back (&Caroline);
    theGroup.push_back (&David);
    theGroup.push_back (&Erin);
    theGroup.push_back (&Frank);
    theGroup.push_back (&Gemma);
    theGroup.push_back (&Hassan);
```

You can use the `->` operator to call methods on pointers to objects, like so:

```
    string GetVote (int round)
    {
        Person *ugh = voteList[round];
        return ugh->GetName ();
    };
```

And:

```
void Voting (const vector<Person *>& voters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voters.size(); i++) {
        int number = (rand() % voters.size());
        Person *myTarget = voters[number];
        voters[i]->Vote (myTarget);
        cout << voters[i]->GetName() << " votes for " << voters[number]->GetName() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this worked beautifully, thank you! I didn't even realize that I was copying my objects. As you can probably tell, I'm rather new at this. :(

Answer (score 3):

When you call `voting` you pass a *copy* of the vector, and the contents will be copied as well.

You should pass this vector as a reference:

```
void Voting (vector<Person>& voters) { ... }
```

You might also want to add some safety checks in `GetVote` to make sure the caller doesn't supply an index out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks! It was the lack of reference, among other things. And good call on the safety checks, working them in now.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Voting (vector<Person> voters)
```

You want to make this a reference. Otherwise, when you get the address of `voters[number]`, you're getting the address of a local variable of your function - making everything go bananas once you try to actually use it.

```
void Voting (vector<Person> &voters)
```

---

Actually that wasn't exactly the problem, although that's still related to references.
You are passing your original `vector` by copy, which means the original `vector` (in the `main` function) is not going to be modified by the function's operations (same goes for its contents, of course). So, all the `Person`s inside have their original state, with an empty `voteList` `vector`.
Obviously, if you try to dereference any of its (non-existent) elements, that's not going to go well !

Comment: I reworked everything so that it's referring to the originals rather than the copy, and it's working like a charm. Thanks!